# Best way to login two different type from same login form

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, servlets, web

I am writing a web application in java that has two different type of users Student & Staff. I want one centralized login for all users but Students must view a different page from teachers .The way I currently implement this is by using one login form and take the username & password and run two queries, one on the student table and one on the staff table. If I get successful response from the user table then I login the user to the student page, otherwise I query the teacher table if I get a successful result I login to the Teachers page, otherwise I give error message that username and password is invalid. What I would like to know is how can I improve this is doing just one query possible and I don't mind editing the database to facilitate this.

Comment: Why is it so important to perform only a single query?  That doesn't sound like a sufficient reason to redesign your database.

Comment: Instead of `select * from student ...` and `select * from staff ...`,  you could simply select from both tables: `select * from student, staff ...` but you haven't show your schema so how are we supposed to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too open-ended for a definitive answer, but it's common to separate [authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication) from [authorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization).

One approach to doing this is to have a table of users and a table of roles, with the user table handling authentication and the role table controlling authorization.  A user is associated with a role (or maybe even multiple roles) by a join table.

With this approach, login does a query against only the user table to determine that a person is a valid user, and other parts of the application query the role or roles associated with the logged-in user to determine whether access to a specific function is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add a dropdownlist within the form so they can select if they want to login as a user or as a staff?